# Запрос в mysql для получения итого

Tags: php, sql, pdo

у меня встала задача, которую ни как не могу решить

есть БД в ней 2 таблицы, в одной (таблица курс)к примеру 2 значения 1 ИД и 2 20

в другой (таблица цены) 6 значений 1 ИД, 2 50, 3 100, 4 150, 5 200, 6 250

как написать mysql  запрос на php pdo что бы 2,3,4,5,6 было умножено на 20 и получен масив?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Особенно п.п. 5 и 3.

Comment: Спасибо, ноо увы незнаю как правильно сформулировать свою мысть и решил максимально просто спросить

Comment: `SELECT p.id, p.p_1 * c.num as p_1,  p.p_2 * c.num as p_2, p.p_3 * c.num as p_3, p.p_4 * c.num as p_4, p.p_5 * c.num as p_5 FROM prices p JOIN course c ON c.id = p.id `

Comment: извините c.num это таблица с которой мы берем сумму на которое будем вножить все p*шки ?
получается что после FROM мы склеиваем таблицу Прайс с ее пшками с таблицей Курс с ее сумой и получаем масив с умноженными цифрами ?

Comment: https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3zbe4ctwb так понятней? Решение конкретной задачи. А, вообще, у Вас скорее всего не правильно спроектирована бд

Comment: Возможно, я только только начал свое обучение, понемаю что может работать как костыль, но это пока не наточу навыки очень сильно облегчит ежедневную работу.

Comment: Низкий Вам поклон и многих лет здравия !

Comment: Там еще и уроки можно по sql проходить ? вообше шикарно.

Comment: @zortwarut А чем обусловлена необходимость 5-6 полей для цены? Если это 5-6 цен разных товаров - вы немного не поняли концепцию реляционной БД. Если одного - странновато, но возможно такие у вас требования

Comment: Прошу прошения, повторюсь, я только только начал изучать. На данном этапе то что я хочу реализовать то как показал InDevX прям аж за глаза. Возможно в будушем когда опыта будет побольше, вся концепция из менится )